# differencing disk opinions

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I've read about the performance issues with dfferencing disks but I still think there is a solid place for them and thats the os boot partition.  If I'm going to have 20 vms on a csv based volume I don't won't to waste the 20+ gigs per guest just for the os boot.  If I get a good base disk with all of the most used applications installed and have the pagefile located somewhere else I don't think the delta's would be that great thus it should not create a performance issue.   Also in a SAN based csv volumes does it make any sense in having the pagefile go to a seperate csv volume?
Any opinions on this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the same. Windows base disc, sysprepped, then differential discs for the specific servers. I upgrade my differential base image every major service pack for new servers, but otherwise taht is it. I really dont think performance is worse... given that i get a higher RAID controller hit rate thanks to not having all the stuff x times ;) Anyhow, it makes no differnce to me, I am more than satisfied with the perforamnce I have.